# I lose all audio when I install the Waveshare drivers on my Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: audio, pi-3, touchscreen

So I've been trying to get my [Waveshare 5inch LCD](http://www.waveshare.com/wiki/5inch_HDMI_LCD) to work with my Raspberry Pi 3, I've gotten the drivers installed and the touch function works fantastically, but once the drivers are installed all audio drivers are just plain gone.

I have tried reloading the audio drivers with `sudo modprobe snd-bcm2835` and it appears to work, but when I do a check with `sudo cat /proc/asound/cards` it will list no sound cards at all. Before I install the drivers for the touch screen the audio works fine.

I don't want to have to deal with buying a USB sound card to use my headphones with the Pi when there is a perfectly good 3.5mm jack I can use for that.

I am using the latest version of Raspbian Jessie that I can find to download off the Foundations website and the latest version of the LCD drivers found on the waveshare wiki linked above.

Comment: I just set up this very touchscreen/drivers last week, but I've never used audio. I'll test it out when I get home tonight.

Comment: For further analysis I would look at the boot messages (`dmesg`) or the syslog (`cat /var/log/syslog`). And grep for snd, sound, and module.

Comment: Did you installed ALSA and Pulseaudio togather?

Answer (score 1):

Check for Pulseaudio and ALSA driver. If they are both installed the sound will never work on Raspbian. You have to delete Pulseaudio.

Answer (score 0):

append this line:

dtparam=audio=on

to /boot/config.txt and reboot.

Comment: Have tried that numerous times, though going to try it again, but it never seems to work to let me have audio, all I still get is the speaker icon when on the desktop just having a X over it

Answer (score 0):

it works.

go terminal mode.

sudo nano /boot/config.txt

add the line 'dtparam=audio=on'

ctrl x to exit
press 'y' to save

press 'enter' to save 'config.txt'

type 'reboot' and enter to reboot

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi! This duplicates [another answer](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/51872/19949) and adds no new content. Please take the [tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [helpcenter](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to see how things work here.